# Can I add buttons in ASP table column and get in which row button was clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, onclick

I have table with 20 to 30 rows and 3 columns. I would like to add fourth column with buttons or something in the cell that I can click on it. And onClick event I need to get info in which row has happened this click.

Table is generated programmatically on the fly.

Can this be done and I beg for some examples.

EDIT 2:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HelpdeskOsControl
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //GenerateTable(getTestData());
        }

        private List<string> getTestData()
        {
            List<string> tData = new List<string>(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                tData.Add("proc" + i + "_" + new Random().Next(100) + "_" + new Random().Next(100));
            }

            return tData;
        }

        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = Processes.Rows.Count; i > 1; i--)
            {
                Processes.Rows.RemoveAt(i - 1);
            }
        }

        protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateTable(getTestData());
        }

        protected void btnKill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblView.Text = ((Button)sender).ID;
        }

        private void GenerateTable(List<string> list)
        {
            int st = 0;
            foreach (string line in list)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                Processes.Controls.Add(tr);

                foreach(String str in line.Split('_'))
                {
                    int index = tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                    tr.Cells[index].Text = str;
                }

                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = "Kill " + st;
                b.ID = "btnKill_" + st;
                b.Click += new EventHandler(btnKill_Click);
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Controls.Add(b);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);

                tr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
                Processes.Rows.Add(tr);
                st++;
            }
            Processes.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            Processes.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            Processes.BorderWidth = 2;
        }

    }
}




<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="HelpdeskOsControl.Test" %>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="465px" Width="417px">
    <asp:Table ID="Processes" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="400px" CssClass="tablesorter">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="ProcessesHeader" runat="server" 
        TableSection="TableHeader">
            <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell1" runat="server">Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell2" runat="server">CPU</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell3" runat="server">Memory</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="TableHeaderCell4" runat="server"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" runat="server" onclick="btnLoad_Click" Text="Load" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" onclick="btnClear_Click" 
            Text="Clear" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblView" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HelpdeskOsControl._Default" %>

<%@ Register src="Test.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Test Control</p>
         <Test:WebUserControl ID="Test" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can please someone checks why this code is NOT working when I comment out `GenerateTable(getTestData());` in Page_Load procedure.

Comment: How are you generating this table? If you're using a GridView, you can add a CommandField...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx

Comment: Best to show how you're creating this table. The button will be part of that as the 4th column.

Comment: I added demo code, which have some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a HTMLtable generated in code behind,

assuming this is how your code looks like,

```
HtmlButton b = new HtmlButton();
b.ClientID = "Button_" + i;
b.Attributes.Add("onClick", "your function(this)");
```

use the suffix part from the parameter in the method to check which butto has been click.
Hope this helps!!
Edit:
You may still go with the above logic. In the click  event of the button ( which appears to be common for all the buttons), you ca use the sender object and get the ID and know which button has been clicked as follows:

```
protected void KillButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string ID = ((Button)sender).ID;
}
```

and you may attach the event handler in this fashion:

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(KillButton_Click);
```

Comment: I want that when I click on the button I get this event in codebehind. I am using Asp table and button.

Comment: Why do you want to comment the GenerateTable(getTestData()); from the page_load event, is it because the table will be loaded twice when you click on load?? You can just add if(!IsPostBack) GenerateTable(getTestData()); to the page load. The method will be called only first time. I am not sure if you want that. Please clarify what you want and what are the problems you are facing

Comment: I want that table is generated only when I Click Load button. 
And that when I click Kill button I get back table without row in which was clicked Kill button.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, because it answers my initial question.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ClientID is read Only...therefore you cannot have the line that tries to set the clientID